# Getting the height of STATUS BAR

Tags: java, android, height, statusbar

I'm tring to write a `private` to get the `status bar's` height.

```
private int statusBar() {
    Rect rect = new Rect();
    int statusBar = rect.top;
    return statusBar;
}
```

Everything is good till now. but when I do:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + statusBar(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

It returns 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just searched the site for a while and got this.

```
private int statusBar() {
    Rect rectgle= new Rect();
    Window window= getWindow();
    window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectgle);
    int StatusBarHeight= rectgle.top;
    int contentViewTop= 
        window.findViewById(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT).getTop();
    int statusBar = contentViewTop - StatusBarHeight;
    return statusBar;
}
```

**The toast:**

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + statusBar(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

It seems working.

**update:**

try this, if didn't work try the other one.

```
private int statusBar() {
    Rect rectgle= new Rect();
    Window window= getWindow();
    window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectgle);
    int statusBar = rectgle.top;
    return statusBar;
}
```

2nd

```
private int statusBar() {
    Rect rectgle= new Rect();
    Window window= getWindow();
    window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectgle);
    int StatusBarHeight= rectgle.top;
    int contentViewTop= 
        window.findViewById(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT).getTop();
    int statusBar = contentViewTop + StatusBarHeight;
    return statusBar;
}
```

Comment: I think you should do that, so you minus from the view and get what you want.

Comment: Weird, it returns -38... Maybe it's because I've added `this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` in onCreate ?

Comment: so your statusbar height is 38. because 0-38 = -38 =)
Check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`Rect frame = new Rect();

 getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(frame);

 int statusBarHeight = frame.top;`

Then `Toast` `statusBarHeight`